# Terraform boolean variable true - based on mapped values

Tags: database, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

#### Expected Behaviour

I would like to make a boolean variable **'var.enable_retention_policy'** true based on the output of mapped value **'var.ds_allmetrics_retention_days'**

#### Actual Behaviour

throws error (see Error output)

#### Error Output

```
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on ..\db\main.tf line 37, in module "diagnostic_mssql_db":
  37:     "WorkloadManagement"     = var.workload_management > 0 ? var.workload_management : var.enable_retention_policy

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are number and bool, respectively.
```

#### Terraform (and AzureRM Provider) Version

#### Affected Resource(s)

- `azurerm_v2.41.0`
- `terraform v0.13.0`

#### Terraform Configuration Files

**Main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                = var.storage_account
  resource_group_name = var.sa_resource_group
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "diagsetting" {
  name               = var.target_resource_name
  target_resource_id = var.target_resource_id
  storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id

  dynamic "log" {
    for_each = keys(var.ds_log_api_endpoints)
    content {
      category = log.value
      enabled  = true

      retention_policy {
        enabled = var.enable_retention_policy
        days    = lookup(var.ds_log_api_endpoints, log.value, 0)
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "metric" {
    for_each = keys(var.ds_allmetrics_retention_days)
    content {
      category = metric.value

      retention_policy {
        enabled = var.enable_retention_policy
        days    = lookup(var.ds_allmetrics_retention_days, metric.value, 0)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Variables.tf**

```
# boolean variable
variable "enable_retention_policy" {
  type        = bool
  description = "toggle on/off the retention policy for the metric"
  default     = false
}

# mapped values
variable "ds_allmetrics_retention_days" {
  type        = map
  description = "Azure monitor diagnostic setting category for retention in days of target resource."
  default     = {}
}
```

**Module call**

```
module "diagnostic_mssql_db" {
  source                  = "github.com/faraday23/terraform-azurerm-monitor-diagnostic-setting.git"
  storage_account         = var.storage_account
  sa_resource_group       = var.sa_resource_group
  target_resource_id      = azurerm_mssql_database.db.id
  target_resource_name    = azurerm_mssql_database.db.name
  enable_retention_policy = var.enable_retention_policy
  ds_log_api_endpoints = { "AutomaticTuning" = var.automatic_tuning > 0 ? var.automatic_tuning : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "Blocks"                      = var.blocks > 0 ? var.blocks : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "DatabaseWaitStatistics"      = var.database_wait_statistics > 0 ? var.database_wait_statistics : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "Deadlocks"                   = var.deadlocks > 0 ? var.deadlocks : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "Errors"                      = var.error_log > 0 ? var.error_log : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "Timeouts"                    = var.timeouts > 0 ? var.timeouts : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "QueryStoreRuntimeStatistics" = var.query_store_runtime_statistics > 0 ? var.query_store_runtime_statistics : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "QueryStoreWaitStatistics"    = var.query_store_wait_statistics > 0 ? var.query_store_wait_statistics : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "SQLInsights"                 = var.sql_insights > 0 ? var.sql_insights : var.enable_retention_policy
  }

  ds_allmetrics_retention_days = { "Basic" = var.basic > 0 ? var.basic : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "InstanceAndAppAdvanced" = var.instance_and_app_advanced > 0 ? var.instance_and_app_advanced : var.enable_retention_policy,
    "WorkloadManagement"     = var.workload_management > 0 ? var.workload_management : var.enable_retention_policy
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the issue is with `WorkloadManagement`. In your case you have mixture of `bool` and `int` which is incorrect. [Conditional Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/conditionals.html) **must be of same type**:

> The two result values may be of any type, but they **must both be of the same type** so that Terraform can determine what type the whole conditional expression will return without knowing the condition value.

Thus, you can use [tonumber](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tonumber.html) to change `bool` to `int`:

**Update based on Martin comment**

The original answer used `tonumber(var.enable_retention_policy)` which was incorrect, as you can't convert `bool` to number. To correct answer is then:

```
"WorkloadManagement" = (var.workload_management > 0 
                       ? var.workload_management 
                       : (var.enable_retention_policy ? 1 : 0))
```

Comment: The Terraform language doesn't allow conversion from bool to number, so I think the smallest working change compared to the original example would be a nested conditional, although it's kinda hard to read: `var.workload_management > 0 ? var.workload_management : (var.enable_retention_policy ? 1 : 0)`. I'd probably try to refactor so that this expression doesn't need to be so complex, but I'm not sure what to suggest instead with the information given.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks, but I'm not sure what do you mean that bool can't be converted to number? The code works and executes fine.

Comment: `tonumber(true)` returns the error `Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert bool to number.`

Comment: @MartinAtkins Ah I see. You are right. My mistake. If you want, you can provide an answer, I will upvote it and delete mine?

Comment: Your answer was on the right track about making the results both have the same type, and the means to achieve that seems like a minor detail in comparison, so I don't think it's necessary for me to repeat all of your answer just for this minor correction. Feel free to edit your answer to include something like my suggested alternative, if you like!